# R, DataFrame - group by multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` about posts looks like this:

```
 post_id   group_id hour(when posted) likes
 1         1        13                  5
 2         1        13                  6
 3         1        23                  3
 4         2        12                  30
 5         2        13                  34
 6         2        22                  10
```

I want to plot likes distribution by hours in each group, so I need a `data.frame` like this one:

```
          0 ... 12 13 ... 22 23   <- hours
gorup#1         0  11         3   <- sum of likes in group#i in xx hour
group#2         30 34     10  0
```

How can I group post by group and by hour?

Comment: Maybe look at `table`? Without at least a few lines of sample data and the expected result from that sample data, it's hard to guess what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Add some sample, hope it help=)

Comment: Have you tried, for example, `aggregate(likes~group+id+hour,df,sum)`??

Comment: Thanks, it's works too.
Xtabs in @AnandaMahto solution present result in more wishfull way.

Comment: @PavelRazumovkij, read up on the multiple examples for aggregating data available here on SO for more options. For example, if you're working with a lot of data, you might want to look into the "data.table" package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", perhaps you can try `xtabs` (since you're just looking for `sum`):

```
> xtabs(likes ~ group_id + hour, mydf)
        hour
group_id 12 13 22 23
       1  0 11  0  3
       2 30 34 10  0
```

To get all the levels for "hour", even if they sum to "0" for all groups, `factor` the "hour" column first.

Another convenient alternative is to use `dcast` from the "reshape2" package.